# My USB audio input channels max_out/clips at ~15%

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, usb-audio

I got an M-track 8 audio device (8 I/Os). It works fine for playback. However, the microphone (48 volt XLR mics) barely make any sound. When recording, they cap out at 15% volume in any application.

- According to the mixer spectrum analyser, they are working totally fine.
- If I redirect the m-track input to the analog output and record it using the built-in mic, then it works correctly
- If I record in macOS or Windows, it works correctly.

So the problem is somewhere in ALSA or the driver. This is a normal USB audio class device, so the driver is very unlikely to be the problem (reproduced in Gentoo, Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 live-usb).

- `alsamixer` show all inputs are at 100%
- `pavucontrol` shows all inputs at 100%
- I tried adding some `.asoundrc` configs to force 96kHz and it did nothing
- The problem has nothing to do with mic boost. The signal is ultra weak

amixer -c2:

```
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Center: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Woofer: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Side Left: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Side Right: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Mono: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'M-Audio M-Track Eight',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 121 [95%] [-6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 121 [95%] [-6.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Center: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Woofer: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Side Left: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Side Right: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'M-Audio M-Track Eight',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

lsusb -vv -d 0763:4003

```
Bus 001 Device 049: ID 0763:4003 M-Audio 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0763 M-Audio
  idProduct          0x4003 
  bcdDevice            1.05
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      2
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0148
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         3
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol      32 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              3 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               2.00
        bCategory               8
        wTotalLength       0x00a7
        bmControls           0x00
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     10 (CLOCK_SOURCE)
        bClockID               41
        bmAttributes            3 Internal programmable clock 
        bmControls           0x07
          Clock Frequency Control (read/write)
          Clock Validity Control (read-only)
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iClockSource            9 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     11 (CLOCK_SELECTOR)
        bClockID               40
        bNrInPins               1
        baCSourceID(0)         41
        bmControls           0x03
          Clock Selector Control (read/write)
        iClockSelector          8 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID             40
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               6 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                42
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                10
        bSourceID               2
        bmaControls(0)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(1)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(2)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(3)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(4)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(5)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(6)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(7)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(8)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            20
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID              10
        bCSourceID             40
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID             40
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                42
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                11
        bSourceID               1
        bmaControls(0)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(1)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(2)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(3)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(4)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(5)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(6)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(7)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(8)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            22
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID              11
        bCSourceID             40
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               7 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              4 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              4 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           2
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats          0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          11 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         2 Decoded PCM samples
          wLockDelay         0x0008
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes           17
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Feedback
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              5 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              5 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          22
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats          0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         2 Decoded PCM samples
          wLockDelay         0x0008
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Device Firmware Update
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             10 
      Device Firmware Upgrade Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             9
        bDescriptorType                    33
        bmAttributes                        7
          Will Not Detach
          Manifestation Tolerant
          Upload Supported
          Download Supported
        wDetachTimeout                    250 milliseconds
        wTransferSize                      64 bytes
        bcdDFUVersion                   1.10
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0148
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         3
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol      32 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              3 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               2.00
        bCategory               8
        wTotalLength       0x00a7
        bmControls           0x00
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     10 (CLOCK_SOURCE)
        bClockID               41
        bmAttributes            3 Internal programmable clock 
        bmControls           0x07
          Clock Frequency Control (read/write)
          Clock Validity Control (read-only)
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iClockSource            9 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     11 (CLOCK_SELECTOR)
        bClockID               40
        bNrInPins               1
        baCSourceID(0)         41
        bmControls           0x03
          Clock Selector Control (read/write)
        iClockSelector          8 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID             40
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               6 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                42
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                10
        bSourceID               2
        bmaControls(0)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(1)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(2)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(3)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(4)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(5)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(6)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(7)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(8)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            20
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID              10
        bCSourceID             40
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID             40
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                42
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                11
        bSourceID               1
        bmaControls(0)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(1)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(2)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(3)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(4)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(5)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(6)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(7)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls(8)     0x0000000f
          Mute Control (read/write)
          Volume Control (read/write)
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            22
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID              11
        bCSourceID             40
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               7 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              4 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              4 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           2
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats          0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          11 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         2 Decoded PCM samples
          wLockDelay         0x0008
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes           17
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Feedback
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              5 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              5 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          22
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats          0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             8
        bmChannelConfig    0x00000000
        iChannelNames          19 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            4
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         2 Decoded PCM samples
          wLockDelay         0x0008
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       254 Application Specific Interface
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Device Firmware Update
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface             10 
      Device Firmware Upgrade Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             9
        bDescriptorType                    33
        bmAttributes                        7
          Will Not Detach
          Manifestation Tolerant
          Upload Supported
          Download Supported
        wDetachTimeout                    250 milliseconds
        wTransferSize                      64 bytes
        bcdDFUVersion                   1.10
```

`pacmd list-sources inputs`:

```
   index: 16
        name: <alsa_output.usb-M-Audio_M-Track_Eight-00.analog-surround-71.monitor>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: RUNNING
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 1040
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-center: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   lfe: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   side-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   side-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max rewind: 11 KiB
        sample spec: s32le 8ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right
                     Surround 7.1
        used by: 5
        linked by: 5
        configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 8.00 .. 743.04 ms
        monitor_of: 7
        card: 5 <alsa_card.usb-M-Audio_M-Track_Eight-00>
        module: 27
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of M-Track Eight Analog Surround 7.1"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "M-Track Eight"
                alsa.long_card_name = "M-Audio M-Track Eight at usb-0000:00:14.0-5.4, high speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.4:1.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.4/1-5.4:1.0/sound/card2"
                udev.id = "usb-M-Audio_M-Track_Eight-00"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "0763"
                device.vendor.name = "M-Audio"
                device.product.id = "4003"
                device.product.name = "M-Track Eight"
                device.serial = "M-Audio_M-Track_Eight"
                device.string = "2"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
```

Here is a recording:

```bsh
parecord -r --format=s24le --file-format=wav ./foo.wav

file ./foo.wav
```

```
./foo.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 24 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

The sound is from the mic and is clipped on the device (vu-meter red bar is shown).

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) Please edit question with output of `amixer -c99 content`, where `99` is the "card number" of the USB device (`aplay -l`). (2) Googling says the device needs a special Window driver, so also add `lsusb -vv` for the M-track to the question, so we can see if there's an alternate interface on top of the audio class interface. (3) Your `asoundrc` will normally get completely ignored under Pulseaudio.

Comment: I added the lsusb and amixer output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious, but two ideas:

1. The USB device has two configurations, though from the information displayed about them, they seem to be identical. So I do not know what they are for. You could try to switch to the other one (with `usb_modeswitch`, unload kernel modules first) and see if that changes anything
2. You are streaming 24 bits in 4 bytes, if I read the descriptors correctly. If the generic USB Audio driver picks out the wrong 3 bytes, you could end up with a most significant byte of zero, which would restrict the level to 12.5% (matching your observed 15%).

   You can verify this by recording (e.g. `parecord`) to some file (WAV or raw) in 24-bit format, and examining it with a hex editor. If the MSB of all samples is zero, even when you produce a volume that clips on Mac or Windows, that would make this very likely.

   In addition, you can use `wireshark` to capture the USB packets, so you can compare if they do have an additional third byte in the samples that doesn't make it into the recorded data.

In that case, it's a bug in the driver, so please file a bug report on the ALSA kernel list.

---

Quick excurse on use cases: Normally people buy something like the M-track 8 to record with multiple mics, e.g. a band where ever member has one or two mics (vocals + instrument). In that case, you'd just get all 8 channels from Pulseaudio (disabling downmixing), and your DAW would select which channels you'd actually record.

Often you'd even completely disable Pulseaudio for that, as it only adds latency, and go directly to ALSA, or use Jack instead of Pulseaudio.

> "I want my laptop to play into my 7.1 surround speakers or my stereo headphone. Then if I make a conference call, I just want people to hear me.

Ok, so you have a single mic, and that's all you have in the use case. You also want to keep Pulseaudio, as you don't have latency issues, and you are using the 8 channels mainly for output.

So have a look at the [module-remap-source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-remap-source) and do something like

```
load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_input.usb-MTRACK.analog-stereo channels=1 master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono
```

where `front-left` is the channel you have your mic on, and `MTRACK` is replaced with the actual name of your M-Track source (use e.g. `pactl list short`). Then record from the new source.

If the only actual problem was that Pulseaudio was downmixing all 8 channels to stereo and reducing the level with that, the you should be good now.

If there's still another problem, please test recording all 8 channels without Pulseaudio and only with ALSA as described in the comments, so we can rule out Pulseaudio and see if the problem is in the ALSA drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with half of the data. I may add wireshark later. Strangely, their appear to alternate between 4 `f` and 4 `0` bytes !?! I assume the volume is "higher" on the playback because somethings magically adds a mix boost (the playback vu-meter is higher than the record vu-meter). But 4 `f` is 32bit... Isn't `s24le` supposed to be uncompressed PCM24? I am a bit confused about what is displayed in `hexdump`. It's been a while since I played with `.wav` (edit: The recorded sound is a single tone, not speech)

Comment: I am confused now: Why does it record stereo when you got 8 channels? Is this Pulseaudio downmixing it? Try to add the channels on the command line, or stop Pulseaudio (e.g. `pasuspender`) and use `arecord`.

Comment: Umm, you are into something! If I add `--channels 2 --no-remix --no-remap` to `parecord`, it now record louder. Still not quite normal, but it is now within mic-boost range.. If there a way to configure each channels to be it's own input? Because the mic is mono, on a mono channel. The fact that it attempts to automagically mix everything into new 2 streams is a rather surprising behavior. To work correctly, it needs to record non-mixed mono.

Comment: As I understand it, the M-track has just 8 channels, without special designations? And you'd normally want to record all 8, and the hardware says "I'll always give you all 8 channels". For the specific case "I only have a single mic attached to the M-track", yes, you could make this into a separate input via Pulseaudio modules, but it'll add latency. But to debug your issue, I still recommend to directly record 8 channels with ALSA only (Pulseaudio stopped/syspended), and see if you still see the problem.

Comment: I don't think I agree here (the "And you'd normally want to record all 8"). The current behavior is unfit for most workflow. For pro audio, this would use virtual patchbay into something like Ardour tracks. So the default "mixer" is definitively unwanted there. My use case is "I want my laptop to play into my 7.1 surround speakers *or* my stereo headphone. Then if I make a conference call, I just want people to hear me. Turning off Pulse doesn't even work since Chrome/Firefox no longer properly support the ALSA API. So right now pulseaudio make an otherwise working hardware soft-bricked?